# Change from free app with in-app purchase to paid app

Tags: android

I want to do the reverse of this: [Change a Paid Android app to a Free app with in-app purchasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018116/change-a-paid-android-app-to-a-free-app-with-in-app-purchasing?rq=1). That is, I have a free Android app with a paid upgrade. I want to switch to just having separate paid and free apps, with people who have made the purchase getting the paid one for free. Is that possible?

Comment: You cannot change the free app (with in-app purchases) to a paid app. I.e. people will have to buy it.

Comment: Please check this link [Stack Overflow : Allow users to download paid app for free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694946/allow-users-to-download-your-own-paid-app-for-free-in-android). And provide the code to those who have purchased in the free version, I guess, in a later update.